# Can I apply for a family visit visa to stay with my husband in the UK before applying for a spouse visa?

Tags: uk-visa

I am a Tunisian and my husband is British. We have been living in Tunis since we got married in July 2017. My husband has been offered a job in the UK (one-year contract) and I plan on applying for a spouse visa to join him. We fulfill the financial requirement for a spousal visa. However, the spouse visa process takes a long time and there are still documents we will need from the UK/we need to let an apartment. We would really like to not be apart for an extended period of time and so we are wondering whether it is OK for me to apply for a 6 month family visit visa. We have a few questions about this:

Can I apply for a visit visa and then apply to change it to a spouse visa from the UK or will I have to come back to Tunis to apply and wait for the decision?

We've read that they are likely to reject a family visit visa application if I state that I intend to stay for the whole 6 months period on the grounds that I don't have "strong ties" to return home (I would have to quit my job in Tunis). Would it be better for me to stay for a month or two at a time then come back to Tunis for some time or does it not make a difference?

Also, we are worried that taking this course of action and staying for 6 months on a visit visa (or worse, being rejected one) may adversely affect my future spouse visa application.

Grateful for any advice!